# Checkbox object in Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

How can I make a new array out of selected objects ?

.ts

```
  selectedObjects: object[];
  objectArray: object[];
```

.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let object of objectArray">
      <input [checked]="selectedObjects" type="checkbox" name="object.name" value="object.property2">{{object.name}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your inputs to the `change` event :

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="updateSelected(object.property2)" name="object.name" value="object.property2">{{object.name}}
```

In your TS :

```
updateSelected(value: string) {
  if (this.selectedObjects.includes(value)) {
    this.selectedObjects.splice(this.selectedObjects.indexOf(value));
  } else {
    this.selectedObjects.push(value);
  }
}
```